# Which publishing feature creates a search site?

Tags: search, feature

I have created some custom WebTemplates for SP2010 and activated a load of publishing features which have in turn created a search site. Does anyone know which feature is likely to create this subsite within my site collection and how I can turn it off?

Also, I have a feature receiver to create a blog subsite. How can I avoid this particular link from being displayed in the top navigation?

Answer (score 0):

Well it does matter which SP license you're havin but on standard its:

"SharePoint Server Standard Site Collection features" 
-> "Features such as user profiles and search, included in the SharePoint Server Standard License."